# Android Multiple Alarm With Different Notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, reminders

My app like reminder, user choose a film and user will set alarm -every day or once a week- on my app. If user want set multiple alarm for different films. I want to send notification every alarm with different content. I tried AlarmService but I can set just one alarm. I search it on Google but I can't find anything for my work. How can I do that? Please say your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to send a broadcast using a pending intent with the information of the movie in the extras and then use a `BroadcastReceiver` to build and display the notification.

This looks like a good example:
https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223

check:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Thank you for your message. I tried this code when I saw your message but that code can set just one alarm like on my work. How can I set multiple alarms?

Comment: Well if the alarm will run every day or every week or whatever, you can call [setRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%2520long,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) and set the interval you need.

Comment: It works, I changed notification id and fix the problem. Thank u for message :) @aaroncio